# NameResolutionFailure in Mono but not .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am making HTTPS POST requests (same problem with HTTP) using C#

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("var1=blah&var2=hah");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)(WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com"));
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

The preceding code works great in both .NET and Mono when I don't have to go through a proxy. When I have to use a proxy, then it works when run on .NET but in Mono fails with the following

```
WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Also, running in a browser with the same proxy configuration works fine. Any reason why Mono would throw a NameResolutionFailure while .NET does not?

There was a similar stackoverflow question that had a work around of using the direct ip when creating the request and then adding the domain to the request.Host.  However, the proxy I have to go through rejects this kind of request.  Help!

Operating System is Windows 7, Mono version is 2.6.5

Comment: Can't site, so comment in stead of answer. I believe this was a bug in Mono that was fixed with a later release (if you are in Windows, it was an issue within the System.dll, I think) - you might Google it!

Comment: stackoverflow should generate an automatic question when tagging questions with the "mono" tag: "what version of Mono are you using?"

Comment: Proxy config is pretty notorious in *nix, there's no centralized configuration point and every app needs to take care of it itself.  It is fairly unlikely that Mono uses the IE settings.  Try a .exe.config file instead that uses the `<defaultProxy>` element.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First of all check your web browse in your phone. If it will be the same situation - then you have to worry about. I had the same situation and it happened all time when EMULATOR doesn't have permission to net. Try on normal device.